# What is the size of logo for Promo-tab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I'm looking the right size for the logo a Promo tab of Gmail.
for some reason, the Logo that I used works well on android but on iPhone it's zoomed-in.

Example of the logo on iPhone:

[image: example of the logo at iPhone]

Example of the logo on Android:

[image: example of the logo at android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*While there is no recommeneded specification for the size of the Promotions tab logo by Google, all their examples use a logo of 48x48px.*

#### More Information:

All best practices for the Promotions tab are given on the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/best-practices) page. For the logo, they only specify protocol rather than image size:

> #### Logo URL
>
> Be sure to use an https (not http) URL. This logo selection only shows in the email preview.

By looking at the examples given by Google, however, you can see that each one uses [this](https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png) sample image, which is 48x48px in size:

**From the [Get started](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview) page:**

```
// WARNING: Before sending email, either point the logo
// at your own image or delete the logo annotation.
//
// If showing a logo, we recommend using an https URL.
// It's not a requirement today, but may be in the future.
"logo": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png"
```

**From the [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/troubleshooting) page:**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="logo" content="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png" />
</div>
```

and:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "PromotionCard",
  "logo": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png"
}
```

So, it can be safely assumed that a logo with 48x48 size, of PNG format, would be sufficient for a Promotions tab logo.

#### References:

- [Best Practices | Promotions tab | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/best-practices)
- [`googleg_48dp.png`: Google Exmaple logo](https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png)
- [Get started | Promotions tab | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview)
- [Troubleshooting | Promotions tab | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/troubleshooting)